# Does a sequence of finite integrals with non-negative integrands which converges on a measure space also converge on any measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ denote a measure space, and let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of non-negative, real-valued functions on $X$ for which each integral in (1) is finite, and suppose that the limit in (1) is finite.

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n\ d\mu \hspace{2in}(1)
\end{equation}

Are these conditions sufficient to insure that for any set  $E$ in the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$
the limit

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E f_n\ d\mu \hspace{2in}(2)
\end{equation}

also exists ?  If so, I would be interested in a proof of this fact for these given conditions. Otherwise, is there a counter-example to show that (2) need not hold for the given conditions ?

Comment: There are very easy counter-examples. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: On $X:=[0,1]$ equipped with Lebesgue measure, consider non-negative functions $f_n$ where $\int f_n=1$ for every $n$, so the limit of these integrals is also $1$. Now consider the subset $E:=[0,\frac12]$. Try to define $f_n$ so that $\int_E f_n$ is an oscillating sequence.

Comment: Based on this counter-example, suppose that the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to a real valued function on $X$.  Will (2) hold with this extra condition ?